# jQuery show/hide issue on data grid onclicking checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have developed this data grid having expand/collapse functionality. Onclicking the row the child rows will get expanded. But the issue here is when i check/uncheck the checkbox the grid expand/collapses which i don't want.

Can anyone fix this issue. Here is the implementation  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fwyf/39/)

thanks,
ravi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your script:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(event){event.stopPropagation()});
```

Comment: The above script is working perfectly but having one issue. On the page load, the grid is still expanding/collapsing when clicking on the checkbox and happening only for the first click. Intresting......:) see the [demo](http://http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/3fwyf/61/)

Comment: @Nahom I've found the problem. In your demo you've declared the extra click handler **within** the click handler for your table row, so it doesn't get declared until the first click has already happened. If you move it down a line it should work as required.